# can i use "amazon-cognito-identity-js" for federated authentication with cognito

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I use "amazon-cognito-identity-js" javascript library to integrate Cognito for my react app. it seems that only supports email/password authentication only.

I wanna use federation authentication (eg: google) with my app.

so is it possible with this library?
I know I can use "aws-amplify".

[related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794834/how-to-implements-aws-cognito-federated-identities-using-amazon-cognito-identity)